# Getting an COMException (Unknown Interface) when calling Application.StartNewUndoEntry() in PowerPoint add-in

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto

while building a VSTO PowerPoint Add-in in C#, I am trying to set my own entries in the undo stack so that the stuff the add-in does can be undone properly as well as by a `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("Undo")`.

I try this by calling `Application.StartNewUndoEntry()`. The result is:
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Unknown Module. Unknown interface. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020001 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNINTERFACE))`

I am completely lost on where this error is coming from and did not find much help searching online. At this point I am suspecting a build configuration or linking problem, although I am not well-versed with the internals of these add-ins to debug it.

Does anybody have an idea? I would be really grateful for some pointers!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am an idiot.
I was using Office 2007, `Application.StartNEwUndoEntry()` is only supported by Office 2010 and later.

Comment: I'd suggest using PIAs that correspond to the lowest Office version supported by your application. In that case you will be sure that used methods and properties exists in all supported Office versions.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I'll look into that.